# laravel form is not submitting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my code

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'restaurants.store', 'id' => 'msform')) }}
<!-- multistep form -->

        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
            <li>Social Profiles</li>
            <li>Personal Details</li>
            <li>Address</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
            {{ Form::text('email', '', array('placeholder' => 'Username'))}}
            {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password'))}}
            {{ Form::password('confirmPassword', array('placeholder' => 'Confirm Password'))}}
            {{ Form::button('next', array('class' => 'next action-button'))}}
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">General Information</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your public profile</h3>
            <input type="text" name="restaurantName" placeholder="Restaurant Name" />
            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" />
            <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Website" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <input type="text" name="mobileNumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>

            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
                <div id="map_manual_address_container">
                    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
                    <div id="mamual_address">
                        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
            {{ Form::submit('submit', array('class' => 'submit action-button')) }}
        </fieldset>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

when I click on submit, nothing happens, I mean that when I click on the button, it is like nothing has been clicked.

#### routes.php

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

#### RestaurantsController

```
<?php

class RestaurantsController extends BaseController {

public function store()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

I dont' know what wrong I am doing I hope you help

Comment: you passed a route as the form action `restaurants.store`, yet you haven't defined a route name.

Comment: @zwacky what do you mean by `you haven't defined a route name` please? I already showed you the `store` function in my controller

Comment: have you tried debugging this? what is the form action in the HTML? what happens if you print "hello world" in your store method?

Comment: my bad, resource automatically adds route names like `restaurants.store`.

Comment: @fire this is from chrome debug `<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8082/ParkingProject/public/restaurants" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="msform"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="TUU8Us2X6qcvKiw8RpYSkrOA0Rui41EiLLG4XcWt"><!-- multistep form -->` and when I echo hello world, still nothing happens, it likes it is not going to the controller at all

Comment: @zwacky so what is the mistake please? i am gonna loose my mind in this issue, 3 hours trying to solve it :( :(

Comment: did you intentionally use `/public` as your project root?

Comment: @zwacky the public folder was exist when I created the project, and I have already a root to this page `http://localhost:8082/ParkingProject/public/restaurants/create` and it is working.

Comment: I solve it guys, sorry I am so stupid

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself, I am an idiot stupid programmer

I have this function

```
$(".submit").click(function () {
    return false;
})
```

and I forget to remove it.

Please forgive me to my stupid question